# JSON Boolean doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, json

I'm struggling a bit with my web application

First time working with JSON for me.

Where the json looks like this

```
{
"Code":"310254351",
"FirstName":null,
"LastName":null,
"NewUser":true
}
```

I can see in my HTML that the 'NewUser' bool comes through perfectly. 
Somehow I cannot get is to work in JS (angular)

```
 $scope.checkForUserProfile = function () {
    $scope.getUserProfile();

    if ($scope.userprofile.NewUser)
    {
        $scope.showWelcome = false;
        $scope.showProfileNew = true;
    }
    else (!$scope.userprofile.NewUser)
    {
        $scope.showWelcome = true;
    }           
}

$scope.getUserProfile = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
     $http.post('http://localhost:49165/Service1.svc/userprofile/get/').then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.userprofile = response.data;
        }, function (errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while getting user profile');
        });
    $scope.loading = false;
};
```

Am I missing some casting or something?

I tried several ways also this doesn't seem to work;

```
 if ($scope.userprofile.NewUser = true){
```

// do something
}

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Check your browser's developer console and you'll see the error(s).

Comment: Where, how and especially **when** is `$scope.userprofile` actually populated with data…?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log($scope.userprofile)` just before the `if()` statement ?

Comment: FYI, this is doing an assignment, and will always pass the condition.  `if ($scope.userprofile.NewUser = true){` You want a comparison `===` instead.

Comment: There are several basic Javascript mistakes in the code, most notably: the single = is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: In what way is this question related to JSON? Also, if this is Angular please tag it as such. The last code example is formatted improperly by the way. What does the console show? When you debug your code, and stop at the `if` statement, what is showing as the value of `$scope.userprofile.NewUser`?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.userprofile` it seems undefined. Should you want to do this:

```
$scope.userprofile = $scope.getUserProfile();
```

Comment: Instead of answering based on a guess, it might be better to ask a comment to clarify that `$scope.getUserProfile()` does in fact set the `$scope.userprofile` value as it appears it might being.

Comment: You right @torazaburo, thanks.  Although not assertiv, It had become clear for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
else (!$scope.userprofile.NewUser)
```

`else` doesn't take a boolean like that! Remove the bit between `()`.

So the `if` becomes:

```
    if ($scope.userprofile.NewUser)
    {
        $scope.showWelcome = false;
        $scope.showProfileNew = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.showWelcome = true;
    }
```